# Custom composer namespace doesn't find class

Tags: php, class, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I'm trying to use my custom namespace for my personal classes.

The directory structure is (as usual):

```
    my_project/
      - src/
         |- myComponent.class.php
         \- myWrapper.class.php
      - vendor
         |- OtherLibrary
         \- Symfony
      - composer.json
      - index.php
```

in my **composer.json** I specify my own namespace with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "my_namespace\\": "src/"
    }
}`
```

then in my PHP code I have something like:

### myComponent.class.php

```
namespace my_namespace;

class myComponent
{
 .... code
}
```

### index.php

```
namespace my_namespace;

require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$component = new myComponent();
```

## Running this I get a:

> Fatal error: Class 'my_namespace\myComponent' not found in /path_to_root/my_project/index.php on line 5

## while...

- I would expect *myComponent* to be searched under *my_project/src/*, as specified in the *composer.json* and as defined into *vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php* (`'my_namespace\\' => array($baseDir . '/src')`).
- I would expect to directly call my custom **myComponent**, when I define the namespace to my own namespace. Am I wrong?

What's wrong in my code and my assumptions?
How should I fix it?

Comment: As you use psr-0, don't you have to add a targetDir() declaration ? https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#target-dir

Comment: I am actually learning about Composer so I'm not sure how should I set this declaration. Is it the targetDir for my custom namespace or the targetDir for my root/project directory? And should I leave the *autoload/psr-0/myNamespace* empty? (as shown in the example on your link) | I don't get what this directive should solve.

Comment: I also tried to change the `"autoload":{"psr-0"}"` to `"my_namespace\\": ""` and to add `"target-dir": "src/"`, but it didn't solve. Still _Class not found_.

Comment: I suggest you to have a look at the vendor/Composer/autoload_psr0.php file (and maybe add this to your question). If you have the chance to switch to psr-4, it is more intuitive.

Comment: I switched to psr-4. And I also found the problems: 1) _.class.php_ should just be _php_ (autoloader doesn't strip it automatically) 2) Shame on me! I had one case-sensitive typo that was preventing to find the right file!

Comment: **Suggestion for everyone (and for myself):** before looking for problems that you cannot solve, try to look first for those that you can solve (even the basic ones!).

Comment: I missed the .class.php. Happy that you could solve your problem.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You found the errors yourself, but here is a quick collection of what the useful autoload directives in Composer do:

1. PSR-0 converts the class name into a path name (underscores and backslashes from namespaces are converted into a directory separator), adds ".php" at the end, and tries to find this file in the path that you have given in the `composer.json` file. A class `myNamespace\myClass` and `"psr-0":{"myNamespace\\": "src"}` will try to load `src/myNamespace/myClass.php`.
2. PSR-4 only works with namespaces. It removed the namespace prefix given in `composer.json` from the full class name, and the remainder is converted into a path, ".php" added at the end, and searched in the path given. A class `myNamespace\myClass` and `"psr-4":{"myNamespace\\": "src"}` will try to load `src/myClass.php`.
3. Classmap autoloading will work by scanning all the files for classes, interfaces and traits (everything that can be autoloaded), and compiles an array map of it. It works with any file name schema and any directory layout, but try to avoid it because it will need an update to the map every time you add a new class. Also, it takes time to scan the files while installing, and it takes some CPU and memory to load and hold that map.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer. Until now I really couldn't find any brief description of the three alternatives, like this one. This will be useful for others I guess too. Thanks.

Comment: Make sure file ends with .php only and not .class.php. Took me some time to notice...